# Variation on Perron's criterion

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I saw Perron's criterion( which is lovely), I was wondering if it can be changed in the following way (so I have the idea for what the proof will be, but not how to find a polynomial to satisfy the needed properties):

Instead of showing all but 1 root lie outside the unit circle, we show that all but 2 lie outside the circle, and we also show those 2 aren't real, it follows that if the polynomial was reducible those 2 would be in the same factor and so it isn't reducible.

Could someone help me build such a general polynomial?

EDIT:

So I want a polynomial
$ a_n*x^n +a_{n-1}*x^{n-1} ...+a_0$ so that $|a_{n-2}| > |a_n|+|a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-3}|...+|a_0|$ and also that it won't have real roots (specifically that it won't have 2 real roots outside of the unit circle), and none of the roots will be on the unit circle, what's the most general one I can find?

Comment: Perron covered that case too, he proved that if
$$a_{n-2}\ge4^{2n-2}(|a_{n-1}|+...+|a_0|)^2$$
with $a_n=1$ and $a_0 \neq 0$, then $p(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: God damn Perron stealing my ideas! Do you happen to have a link where I can view the proof and details?

Comment: I read it on this [article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2301357?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (pag. 375), but the proof is not presented.

Comment: What do you mean by the most general ? For example, I have modestly tested on this respect polynomials $2 x^4 + 3 x^3 + m x^2 + 5x+4$ for $m=15 \cdots 50$. For all $m$ in that range, all their roots are complex, one pair  (of conjugate roots) is in inside unit disk, the other pair is outside).

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm trying to find the most general "criterion" of irredcubility that is proved as I mention.